# NSString field changes his type randomly

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsstring

I have a problem that droves me crazy.

***Situation***: I have a table that fills everytime with new TableViewCells. There are 3 cells, each one has a UILabel and UITextField.  For table repaint (when because of scroll cell goes out of screen and user scrolls back to see this cell) there are creates new object of TableViewCell, UILabel and UITextField.
I want dynamically save input value of TextField to NSString and create such NSString field and fill it with value in TextField listener UIControlEventEditingChanged.

***Problem*** : When after scroll back cell must be inserted into table i want to fill TextField with value, saved in NSString field. 
*BUT! Everytime this field-variable changes its type*. There are my logs - you can  see first table creation, when my NSString has appropriate type NSCFString. Also there you can see UIControlEventEditingChanged-listener of TextField and logs with >> signal that i want after scrool insert NSString-field value into TextFied in new cell. Before setting text i check type of my "NSString"-field and you can see that every time i have random type of this field.
Can anyone explane me WTF with this code? I'm new to Iphone, so I guess the problem lies in the principles of objective c

```
    // first table creation - all right
2014-09-09 11:34:31.713 BooksPager[1436:207] lazyPatient Class >> NSCFString
2014-09-09 11:34:31.714 BooksPager[1436:207] lazyPatient Value >> 

==========================
// typing text into TextField
2014-09-09 11:37:05.371 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = q
2014-09-09 11:37:05.561 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = qw
2014-09-09 11:37:05.769 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = qwe
// *scrolling and cell goes out of screen
// *scrolling back
// *new cell created with new TextField object, get type of lazyPatientNameSelected variable 
//  before set it value to TextField
2014-09-09 11:36:13.215 BooksPager[1436:207] lazyPatient Class >> __NSArrayM  //HERE!
2014-09-09 11:36:14.416 BooksPager[1436:207] lazyPatient Value >> (
    "<WebThreadCaller: 0x4c60f40>",
    "<WebThreadCaller: 0x4c60f40>"
)

2014-09-09 11:37:05.371 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = a
2014-09-09 11:37:05.561 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = as
2014-09-09 11:37:05.769 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = asf
2014-09-09 11:37:14.989 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatient Class >> __NSCFSet  //HERE!
2014-09-09 11:37:16.164 BooksPager[1465:207] lazyPatient Value >> {(
)}

2014-09-09 11:47:02.392 BooksPager[1541:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = a
2014-09-09 11:47:02.532 BooksPager[1541:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = as
2014-09-09 11:47:11.205 BooksPager[1541:207] lazyPatient Class >> NSInvocation  //HERE!
2014-09-09 11:47:12.243 BooksPager[1541:207] lazyPatient Value >> <NSInvocation: 0x4c57c70>

2014-09-09 12:49:25.502 BooksPager[1720:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = q
2014-09-09 12:49:25.631 BooksPager[1720:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = qw
2014-09-09 12:49:25.728 BooksPager[1720:207] lazyPatientNameSelected = qwe
2014-09-09 12:49:33.221 BooksPager[1720:207] lazyPatient Class >> UITextTapRecognizer  //HERE!
2014-09-09 12:49:39.450 BooksPager[1720:207] lazyPatient Value >> <UITextTapRecognizer: 0x4c98ee0; state = Possible;     delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UITextField 0x4c84030>; target= <(action=oneFingerDoubleTap:,     target=<UITextInteractionAssistant 0x4c884b0>)>; numberOfTapsRequired = 2>
```

Here is my code:

```
@interface PatientCardViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSString *lazyPatientNameSelected;

}

@end

@implementation PatientCardViewController

// .  .  .  .  

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];   
    lazyPatientNameSelected = @"";
}

// .  .  .  .  

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


switch ([indexPath section]) {
    case 0:
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 130);
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];


        UILabel *lIPServerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 30)];
        lIPServerLabel.text = @"Enter patient's last name";


        UITextField *tfServerPath = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 30)];
        tfServerPath.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        tfServerPath.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        tfServerPath.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tfServerPath.tag = 11;

        NSLog(@"lazyPatient Class >> %@", NSStringFromClass([lazyPatientNameSelected class]));
        NSLog(@"lazyPatient Value >> %@", lazyPatientNameSelected);

        tfServerPath.text = lazyPatientNameSelected;

        [tfServerPath addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];


        [cell.contentView addSubview:lIPServerLabel];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:tfServerPath];              

        [lIPServerLabel release];                
        [tfServerPath release];


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }   

        break;

    case 1:
    {
    // .  .  .  .  similar  .  .  .  .
        break;

    case 2:        
    // .  .  .  .  similar  .  .  .  .    
        break;
    }
}

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing :(UITextField*) theTextField{    

    switch (theTextField.tag) {
    case 11:

        lazyPatientNameSelected = theTextField.text;
        NSLog(@"lazyPatientNameSelected = %@", lazyPatientNameSelected);

        break;
    }

}

@end
```

Reuse of cells to me does not fit. This is a simplification of my real code

Comment: That's a weird error for sure and something is very wrong.

Comment: Oh, i forgot Xcode 4.0, ios 4.3

Comment: Add those `NSLog()` calls where `lazyPatientNameSelected` is assigned in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`.

Comment: In TextField listener there are all right - variable has NSCFString

Comment: logs:

2014-09-09 13:25:14.614 BooksPager[1850:207] lazyPatient Class >> NSCFString
2014-09-09 13:25:14.616 BooksPager[1850:207] lazyPatient Value >> q
2014-09-09 13:25:17.329 BooksPager[1850:207] lazyPatient Class >> NSCFString
2014-09-09 13:25:17.332 BooksPager[1850:207] lazyPatient Value >> qw
2014-09-09 13:25:18.856 BooksPager[1850:207] lazyPatient Class >> NSCFString
2014-09-09 13:25:18.861 BooksPager[1850:207] lazyPatient Value >> qwe`

Comment: OK so it looks like it's not happening in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` so there must be somewhere it's being assigned...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem is in this line **tfServerPath.text = lazyPatientNameSelected** - change on tfServerPath.text = [lazyPatientNameSelected copy];

Comment: Thanx from Kyiv), but it's not working(. lazyPatient variable still changes type. For me as java developer this is nonsense. Maybe i have wrong declaration in @interface? using char*, NSMutableString also without result

Comment: I'm not sure, but try to change variable to property like that:

Comment: `@interface PatientCardViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lazyPatientNameSelected;

@end`, and get access to this property everywhere like - self.lazyPatientNameSelected

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I've found where problem was. I've used `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` method that listens every new  symbol entered into textfield.
But when I started to use  `textFieldDidEndEditing()` method - problem gone away and i've got a value from `lazyPatient` variable.